# Giving a WPF treview to do Richtext (Xaml) displaying and editing and drag drop

Tags: wpf

To give the ability to display and edit Richtext (Xaml) inside a treeview item,I have used a bindable Richtextbox (custom user control that used a richtextbox) to the HierachicalDataTemplate that used to populate the TreeViewItems.

This works fine but at the same time I want to have the drag and grop functionality in the treeview. My problem is when I click on the richtextbox (inside the treeviewitem) and do a drag it will do the richtextbox content dragging. What I want is to drag the treeviewitem insted (fire the drag and drop events of the treeviewitem). 
NOTE: If I used a textblock this can be done but can't display richtext. Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger your drag from the on the "Preview" mouse events rather than the regular ones, and set the Handled flag in PreviewMouseMove when doing a drag so the RichTextBox never sees the MouseMove.

For example, you might record the mouse down location in PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, then if you receive a PreviewMouseMove with the left button still down you can set e.Handled=true and then call DoDragDrop in a dispatcher callback.

The reason this works is that RichTextBox uses the regular (non-preview) mouse events.

Comment: Mr. Burns you saved my life. I did everything except the most valubale thing you mentioned. Thanks a lot.